# Zend_Search_Lucene and range search

Tags: zend-framework, search, lucene, zend-search-lucene

I have a bunch of int key fields in my index and trying to do a simple range search like this:

```
`gender:1 AND height:[120 TO 180]`
```

This should give me male in the height range 120 to 180. But for some reason i get this exception:

```
`At least one range query boundary term must be non-empty term`
```

How would i debug this? Is it just Zend_Search_Lucene being buggy?

Answer (score 0):

This is [an open bug](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-5227) in the query parser of the Zend Framework. Created in december 2008 with high priority... and still unsolved.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to change default Analyzer to TextNum to allow number before finding

ZF2:

```
\ZendSearch\Lucene\Analysis\Analyzer\Analyzer::setDefault(new \ZendSearch\Lucene\Analysis\Analyzer\Common\TextNum\CaseInsensitive());
```

Second, your date field MUST be a keyword, not text.